# Git for TFS: opening 2 branches on the same time

Tags: git, visual-studio, tfs

**Situation**

I have an application on TFS Git (2013)

I need to open the source with VS in two different branches at the same time on the same PC. Say branch1 and branch2.

**My problem**

When I launch branch1 (F5), the run takes some files in branch2 instead branch1.
VS branch2 declared it is branch1 even if it has code source of branch2

**What I tried**

I copied branch2 code to another directory that is not a git repository. This solved nothing.
I don't even understand from where Git retrieve the new location.

I tried disconnecting VS from TFS.

**What I need**

Doing the job on the same computer. I also need to commit on branch1

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I end up by creating opening the alternative branch on another VM

Not the best solution, but it's working